# Multithreaded TIdHTTP file download with filestream results in corrupted file

Tags: c++builder, indy, indy10

I've followed quite a few examples of creating a multithreaded file-download using TIdHTTP component, but I'm stumped with the following problem:

But first, a simplified version of my code.

This part calculates the size of the file that needs to be downloaded:

```
TIdHTTP* tcpClient = new TIdHTTP(NULL);
tcpClient->ProtocolVersion = pv1_1;
tcpClient->Head(URL);
__int64 LSize = tcpClient->Response->ContentLength;
System::Classes::TFileStream *STFile = new System::Classes::TFileStream(FFileName, fmCreate);
try
{
    STFile->Size = LSize;
}
__finally
{
    delete STFile;
};
delete tcpClient;
```

Next is a part of the Execute method of a thread that gets called multiple times by my MainForm. FStartPos is the start position in the file for that thread (i.o.w first thread starts at position 0), FEndPos is the end of the block that needs to be retrieved:

```
TFileStream *LStream = new TFileStream(FFileName, fmOpenWrite | fmShareDenyNone);
LHttpClient = new TIdHTTP(NULL);
LHttpClient->ProtocolVersion = pv1_1;
LHttpClient->Request->BasicAuthentication = true;
LHttpClient->Request->Username = FUsername;
LHttpClient->Request->Password = FPassword;
try
{
    LHttpClient->OnWork = ReceiveDataEvent;
    try
    {
    try
    {
      LStream->Seek(FStartPos, TSeekOrigin::soBeginning);
      LHttpClient->Request->Range = "bytes="+UnicodeString(FStartPos)+"-"+UnicodeString(FEndPos);
      LHttpClient->Get(URL, LStream);
      IsFin = true;
    } catch(Exception &e)
    {
        // log the error
    }
    }
    __finally
    {
        LHttpClient->Disconnect();
        delete LHttpClient;
    }
}
__finally
{
    delete LStream;
}
```

When I try to download e.g. an 87MB file, I create 5 download threads, so each thread should be downloading 17MB odd. What I see happening, is that the file gets created (and reports 87MB in size). Usually thread number 3 finishes first, and the file size jumps to 52MB, then thread 1 finishes and the file size jumps to 17MB, and lastly thread 4 finishes with the file now at 69MB (instead of the 87MB is started as).

I have a feeling I'm either using TFileStream incorrectly, or using it in a way that it wasn't designed to be used in.

My question is, is my code wrong? Or is there a better / more appropriate way to write from multiple threads to a single file, but each in its own block?

(I'm running C++ Builder 10.1 with the built in Indy 10 I think)

Thanks in advance for any advice.

-G-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your problem is that your worker threads are using the `fmOpenWrite` flag when creating the `TFileStream`:

> Open the file for writing only. **Writing to the file completely replaces the current contents.**

This means that each thread is wiping out whatever is already in the file and resetting its size to 0!

For what you are attempting, you need to use `fmOpenReadWrite` instead:

> Open the file to modify the current contents **rather than replace them**.

That being said, there are some other things to consider:

- After `Head()` exits, you should make sure that the `Response->AcceptRange` property is set to `"bytes"`.  If it is not, DO NOT spawn multiple threads to download the file, as the server will ignore whatever you assign to the `Request->Range` property, and each request will download the entire file in full.
- when you do spawn multiple threads for downloading ranges, after `Get()` has received the response headers, you should check the `Response->ContentRange...` properties to make sure you are getting what you expected, and to handle the case when the server might send you a smaller range than you requested.  For instance, you can do that checking in the `OnHeadersAvailable` event, and if something unexpected happens then you can cancel the download (by raising an exception) before anything gets written to the `TFileStream`.  This is especially important for range handling, in case you get a `200` response (receiving the whole file) instead of a `206` response (receiving only a range of the file).
- the `Request->Range` property is deprecated, you should be using the `Request->Ranges` property instead:

  ```cpp
  //LHttpClient->Request->Range = "bytes="+UnicodeString(FStartPos)+"-"+UnicodeString(FEndPos);      
  TIdEntityRange *range = LHttpClient->Request->Ranges->Add();
  range->StartPos = FStartPos;
  range->EndPos = FEndPos;
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Remy. I've changed the code accordingly (fmOpenReadWrite instead of fmOpenWrite) but I'm still getting the same behavior. Whichever thread ends first, that seems to be the new filesize of the file. I've also tried to write 8 bytes at the end of file when I create it, to see if its perhaps an OS caching issue, but it also didn't help.

Comment: What you describe is not how `TFileStream` works. `fmOpenReadWrite` works just fine with pre-allocated files. As long as you write only within the pre-allocated area, the file size should not change. `TFileStream` does not change the file size unless you write new data past the current EOF. If you are calculating your ranges correctly, and the file on the server is not changing while you are downloading, then you should not be experiencing this behavior.

Comment: This is easy to test and verify without using HTTP. Start with just the main thread, have it create and size a file, then open a bunch of streams to it, write some data to each stream one at a time, and then close them all. You should end up with a coherent file. Now repeat the same test using threads, and you should have the same result.  Then add HTTP.

Comment: I think it has something to do inside of TIdHTTP's Get method and how it handles the stream.

If I replace the TFileStream with a TMemoryStream in the Get method, then copy the TMemoryStream to the TFileStream object using CopyFrom, then the file size stays correct at 89MB and the file is not corrupted when all the threads finish.

Comment: If the response data is not encoded/compressed in any way, `TIdHTTP` will end up passing the output stream directly to `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` using the `Response.ContentLength` as the byte count to read. `ReadStream()` does assign the `Stream.Size` to be `Stream.Position + Count`. That could be what you are seeing happen. If the response is encoded/compressed in any way, `TIdHTTP` uses a temp stream for reading and then copies that to the target stream when ready, and that will not assign the `Stream.Size`.

Comment: You could write a custom `TFileStream` descendant that disables the `Size` property setter so it won't resize your preallocated file.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll go with that solution, thanks a million for the advice Remy.